# iOS swift: autoresize collection view nested inside a table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Evening,

I have the following design:

- red box: is a table row
- orane box: is a collection view
- blue box: is    a collection cell

When a collection view is empty I would like the row, or the collection view to autoresize to 0.

Currently I got this:

[image]

So I want the orange box autoresizing to height = 0 when there aren't blue box.

I know that I should use a constraint of collectionView Height and set to 0 when is empty.

But i have the outlet in the table cell and the collection delegate into the view controller. And I don't know how to accomplish this.

Any tips? With some code example please :P

Comment: Read Article on
Self-sizing Table View Cells

Comment: could you give me the link at least? :D

Comment: Here you can find how to set auto resizing table view cell : https://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/ . I hope this helps you!

Comment: this is not useful in my case...

Comment: in heightForRowAt method check the size of collection array and return 0 if array is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to resize collectionView depending on its content automatically.

What you can actually do is add constraint of height to your CollectionView and set it to 0 if it's empty.

Then, your cell will have intrinsic height, if you connect CollectionView bottom and top to it accordingly (which you possibly already done)

The last step will be to set **tableView.rowHeight** to **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**. Probably it will work :)

Comment: If I use UITableViewAutomaticDimension the table rows ignore the collection view height and collapse... Probably because the collection view isn't already set

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
         heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

function. In this function, for the corresponding row, **return 0**.